# How to convert Application Package SID to usable format

Tags: powershell, windows-firewall, windows-security

I try to export full info about certain Windows Defender Firewall with following code:

```
 $rule = (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Start")[0]
 $ApplicationFilter   = @($rule | Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter)
 $AddressFilter       = @($rule | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter)
 $PortFilter          = @($rule | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter)
 $SecurityFilter      = @($rule | Get-NetFirewallSecurityFilter)
 $ServiceFilter       = @($rule | Get-NetFirewallServiceFilter)
 $InterfaceFilter     = @($rule | Get-NetFirewallInterfaceFilter)
 $InterfaceTypeFilter = @($rule | Get-NetFirewallInterfaceTypeFilter)
```

Problem is that command $rule | Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter gives answer in following form:

```
 Program : Any
 Package : S-1-15-2-283421221-..........-..........-.........-..........-..........-..........
```

instead of name of package and username like in Windows Defender Firewall console.

I spent a few hours on searching how to convert this special SID to usable form, but I've had no luck. I know, that the rule which has app package configured get value of 'Owner' property - this value is SID of user who owned package which SID is mentioned in

```
($rule | Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter).Package
```

but I still don't know how to get name of package
Does anybody know how to do it?

LukiD

Comment: I like using for debugging Format-Table which does a great job of enumerating through objects.  Try : $rule | format-Table

Comment: I know it's the appxpackage microsoft.windows.startmenuexperiencehost from the gui at least.

Comment: @js2010: I know it, but when you export full set of FW rules it could be difficult to remember which  Application Package SID has which human-readable name.

Comment: I couldn't find an obvious way to go from one to the other in powershell.  It's a good question.  I even looked in the appx manifest.

Comment: @jdweng: format-table doesn't help at all because wanted information is not part of object produced by Get-NetFirewallRule. To get information about programs / application packages associated with certain FW rule you have to run another cmdlet Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter. I suppose that this second cmdlet lookup in other "FW internal array"

Comment: How about `Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName Start | select Group`.  That seems to have the program name.

Comment: @js2010: I also have looked up in package manifest files.

Comment: Then use Get-NetFirewallRule | Format-Table

Comment: @js2010: in this case it is true, but look at FW rules from group "Work or school account" - they are associated with package microsoft.aad.brokerplugin

Comment: I guess that's right?

Comment: The program string has `@{ }` around the name.

Comment: @jdweng: I've checked once more your suggestion and when I use `$rule | ft -Property Group` I get quite promising result:

Comment: `Group                                                                                                                                                       
-----                                                                                                                                                       
@{Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_10.0.20348.1_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy?ms-resource://Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost/StartMenuExpe
rienceHost/PkgDisplayName}`

Comment: But I cannot pass this result into any variable to draw essential info

Comment: `$_.group -replace '@{|\?ms-resource:.*'` to get the name.

Comment: ok - I found the way to put output of format-table or format-list to variable

Comment: @js2010: when you use `$ftrule = $rule | ft -Property Group` you get  garbage in variable $ftrule - you can't use in any simple manner content of this variable, but when you use `$ftrule = $rule | ft -Property Group | out-string` you get simple string in variable $ftrule. With simple string you can make everything, almost... ;-)

Comment: Don't use format-table in calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the group has the name if it's an appx program?  (appx is the enemy of administrators)

```
$rule = (Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Start")[0]
if ($rule.group -match '@{.*') { 
  $appxname = $rule.group -replace '@{|_.*' 
}
$appxname

Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost
```

Here's 90 appx firewall rules.  Sometimes the funny @{ } string is in the Displayname as well.  An Intel program even has a unicode '®' in the title.

```
get-netfirewallrule | % {
  if ($_.group -match '@{.*') { 
    $appxname = $_.group -replace '@{|_.*' 
    $displayname2 = $_.displayname -replace '@{|_.*' 
    $_ | select @{n='displayname2';e={$displayname2}},@{n='appxname';e={$appxname}}
  }
}

displayname2                               appxname
------------                               --------
Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager   Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager
Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost      Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost
Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost      Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost
Start                                      Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost
Work or school account                     Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin
Intel® Graphics Command Center             AppUp.IntelGraphicsExperience
Windows Feature Experience Pack            MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS
...
```

Comment: Your solution is almost ok - on my server I found one group of FW rules which does not contain name of app package - Group has name: "Windows Feature Experience Pack" - app package name: MicrosoftWindows.Client.cbs_cw5n1h2txyewy

Comment: But generally it makes job